# compressing a list of files by using tar

Tags: tar, compression

what I am trying to do is to compress a list of files using tar.

So what I am doing is

```
sudo tar -pcf filename.tgz `cat filename.list`
```

so if there is a directory on the list like this

```
/home/vmuser/.gconf
```

tar compresses everything in that folder. However what I want is to just add exactly whatever is on the list.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear on why you don't just take the directory name off filename.list if you don't want that directory's contents to be tar'ed. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that tar does not actually compress files, it just puts them all into one file (this is called _archiving_ the files).  Just naming the output file .tgz will not cause the file to be compressed - you will also need to use the z flag (i.e. `tar pczf filename.tgz`) which compresses the resulting tar file using `gzip`.

Comment: Do you want to tar the info in the folder inode, or do you just want to skip folders in the file list?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `tar` all files listed in `filename.list`, you should use the `tar -T filename.list` command rather than `tar 'cat filename.list'`.

From  the `tar` manpage:

```
 -T, --files-from FILE
       get names to extract or create from FILE
```

Using `-T` will prevent you from getting the error:

```
-bash: /bin/tar: Argument list too long
```

if you try to compress a large number of files.

---

In order to prevent recursive compression of directories, use the `--no-recursion` flag, as suggested by @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. The final command becomes:

```
tar -pcf filename.tgz -T filename.list --no-recursion
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `tar(1)` man page:

```
   --no-recursion
          avoid descending automatically in directories
```

Comment: :I am not clear on the answer you gave.  Can you edit your response to include the instructions needed to answer the question, and maybe sugeest how this will resolve it?

Comment: `tar --no-recursion ...` It will solve it because tar will not recurse subdirectories.